# How do I import data from the last occupied cell in a column from a separate spreadsheet?

Tags: indexing, google-sheets-formula

So I've been running into an issue combining the two functions listed in the title. I'm trying to import the last occupied row in column E in a separate spreadsheet. Here is my current code:
IMPORTRANGE("other_spreadsheet","specified tab in spreadsheet",INDEX(E2:E,COUNTA(E2:E)))

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please rework your post: 1. Eleborate on what exactly the issue is and also update the title to name the issue. 2. Make it easy for others to reproduce your problem. 3. `indexing` is probably not an appropriate tag – look at its description. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL_or_ID", "Sheet1!E2:E"), "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

or:

```
=IF(A2=1, IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!E2:E"&
 MAX(IFERROR((IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!E2:E")<>"")*(ROW(2:100000))))), )
```

---

### UPDATE 1:

delete column B and use in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(A2:A=1,IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "Purchase_Order!E2:E"),
 IF(A2:A=2,IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "High_Tower!C2:C"),
 IF(A2:A=3,IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "Hotline!D2:D"), ))))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE 2:

delete column B and use in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(A2:A=1,IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "Purchase_Order!E"&MAX(
  IFERROR((IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "Purchase_Order!E2:E")<>"")*(ROW(2:10000))))),
 IF(A2:A=2,IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "High_Tower!C"&MAX(
  IFERROR((IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "High_Tower!C2:C")<>"")    *(ROW(2:10000))))),
 IF(A2:A=3,IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "Hotline!D"&MAX(
  IFERROR((IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "Hotline!D2:D")<>"")       *(ROW(2:10000))))), ))))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mpP3gzOsY0Jo1vg9Ms2YxOmvUlRE1libuE9lVIA8Rqo/edit#gid=1150732384)

---

### UPDATE 3:

use in B2 and drag down:

```
=IF(A2=1, INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "Purchase_Order!E2:E"), COUNTIF(A$2:A2, 1)),
 IF(A2=2, INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "High_Tower!C2:C"),     COUNTIF(A$2:A2, 2)),
 IF(A2=3, INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg", "Hotline!D2:D"),        COUNTIF(A$2:A2, 3)), )))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mpP3gzOsY0Jo1vg9Ms2YxOmvUlRE1libuE9lVIA8Rqo/edit#gid=881895523)

Comment: That didn't work for me. The data in the cell that I am referencing is a mix of letters and numbers (if that matters). I should clarify as well, I'm using the "IF" function also. Sorry for not mentioning that sooner. Here is the code with "IF" inserted. =IF(A2=1,(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!E"&ROW(E2))). With that I obviously get the matching Row/Column but need to modify to get the last occupied in that column. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. I did that code and it is simply adding a number on the code in E2 (AJ234), making it AJ234(2 for row 2, 4 for row 4, etc). The next code in E3 that needs to pull over is YU890.

Comment: @Aschmal can you share a copy of your sheets?

Comment: Original spreadsheet I need to pull data from, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kkMHXRaaPv0IMZgFofXPROeCNL8OLvyPxoT60gKuryg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Spreadsheet I need to populate, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MCXo4jYUPPm_zGXxHi8rWkHFa3Qlk_gXil1bI001BpA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Obviously it's a template that will be populated as the year goes on.

Comment: IError
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B3.

Comment: Sorry that sent, the error message is coming up. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Aschmal answer updated... see UPDAT 2... and also sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mpP3gzOsY0Jo1vg9Ms2YxOmvUlRE1libuE9lVIA8Rqo/edit#gid=1150732384

Comment: Same message coming up. However, the first time you select 1, it should read the first code (in this case, AJ234), the second time you select 1 (no matter how far down the column, there could be a 2, a 3, and another 2 selected form the drop down menu between the next 1) it should read the second code (YU890) and so on. It shouldn't repeat the same code from the first occupied cell. The same for the other tab links. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I've had it recommended to use Query but can't seem to figure out how to make that work with the IF and IMPORTRANGE either.

Comment: It could also be a combination with INDEX, which I've gotten to work on the same tab as it is entered (see Purchase_Order tab).

Comment: @Aschmal see UPDATE 3

Comment: That did it! THANK YOU!